# Symfony 4 SQLSTATE[42000] Specified key was too long

Tags: mysql, symfony, utf-8, doctrine-orm, orm

I am trying to create database from Entity in Symfony 4. However the result is:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

I know this is because it is trying to use utf8mb4 charset and utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation. I've tried to replace my doctrine.yaml file to utf8 and utf8_unicode_ci as well as:

```
@ORM\Table(name="users", options={"collate"="utf8_unicode_ci", "charset"="utf8", "engine"="MyISAM"})
```

But it's still trying to use utf88mb4. How can I force it to use utf8?

Comment: Don't use MyISAM.  See 767 workarounds [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have found an answer, so basically I had a lot of migration files and php was constantly trying to create database with old configuration. To properly create it I deleted Migrations directory and used

`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`.

That helped, now creator used new configuration.

Comment: This is not a complete answer unfortunately.  I'm having the same issue with the SQL code generated by Symfony migrations, but I'm running the code directly on the database.  I think there's an underlying issue with Doctrine.

Answer (score 7):

Hi i get the same error :
**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes**

I fix it with change **length to 191** like this :
**@ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)**

Answer (score 3):

**error** : *In PDOConnection.php line 88:
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was t
  oo long; max key length is 767 bytes*

**framework** : Symfony 4.4

**Solution** :

Update the file  ***config/doctrine.yaml***

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        server_version : '5.0'
        charset: utf8
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8
            collate: utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 1):

We have update the "server_version" to "mariadb-10.1.34" and "charset" to "utf8mb4" in "config/doctrine.yaml". After the update we have to run below command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:drop
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

Here is the "config/doctrine.yaml" for your refrence.

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    url: "%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%"
    server_version: "mariadb-10.1.34"
    charset: utf8
    default_table_options:
      charset: utf8
      collate: utf8_unicode_ci
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
      App:
        is_bundle: false
        type: annotation
        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity"
        prefix: 'App\Entity'
        alias: App
```

Ref: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27166#issuecomment-524041055

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for me:

**Change 255 to 191 on the VARCHAR -- you lose any values longer than 191 characters (unlikely?);**

[Reference](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes)